# How can I get my reset button to work using JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript

I'm starting a coding class and one of my assignments is to get a box to grow, change to blue, shrink, and reset.  I have the first three but I'm not sure how to go about getting the reset button done.

```js
$("#boxGrow").on("click", function() {
    $("#box").animate({height:"+=35px", width:"+=35px"}, "fast");
})

$("#boxShrink").on("click", function() {
    $("#box").animate({height:"-=35px", width:"-=35px"}, "fast");
})

$("#boxBlue").on("click", function() {
    $("#box").css("background-color", "blue");
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button class="btn" id="boxGrow">Grow</button>
    <button class="btn" id="boxBlue">Blue</button>
    <button class="btn" id="boxShrink">Fade</button>
    <button class="btn" id="boxReset">Reset</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just set the height and width to the original height and width of the box and change the color back to orange on `boxReset` click

Comment: Try `$("#box").animate({height:"150px", width:"150px"}, "fast").css("background-color", "orange");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To easily reset the inline styles, you can use `$("#box").removeAttr("style");`, however this will remove all inline CSS on the element. The solution to this would be to put your initial styles in a `<style>` tag, so your code would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"
    ></script>
    <style>
      #box {
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: orange;
        margin: 25px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box"></div>

    <button class="btn" id="boxGrow">Grow</button>
    <button class="btn" id="boxBlue">Blue</button>
    <button class="btn" id="boxShrink">Fade</button>
    <button class="btn" id="boxReset">Reset</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
$("#boxGrow").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").animate({ height: "+=35px", width: "+=35px" }, "fast");
});

$("#boxShrink").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").animate({ height: "-=35px", width: "-=35px" }, "fast");
});

$("#boxBlue").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").css("background-color", "blue");
});

$("#boxReset").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").removeAttr("style");
});
```